# What does it take to build Salesforce SDK 2.0 functionality into my existing iOS app

Tags: security, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

I have built an iOS app and now I need to modify it with **Salesforce** connectivity. Question: I know what is needed to get certain Salesforce related functionality embedded into my XCode project (OAuth to control logins and RestAPI to pass data back and forth) but HOW do I create or add this functionality to my existing project?

Comment: Again, did you read the documentation? You download the SDK from github, run the install script, and add the required files to your Xcode project.

Comment: There it is: in a section called Upgrading Native iOS apps, step by step, just what I needed! Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is really answered by Jonathan Hersh's, for detailed step by step instructions go to the **Salesforce Mobile SDK Development Guide** section: Migrating from the previous release | Migrating iOS applications | Upgrading Native iOS Apps